# SQL Query not inputting value of my variable

Tags: asp.net, sql

I'm having some trouble writing a query using variables. Here's my code

```
Dim bondnumber as String = "69836"

Dim PasswordCheck As String = "DECLARE @investor varchar(10), 
@thepassword varchar(20), @linkedserver2 varchar(25), @sql varchar(1000) "
PasswordCheck += "SELECT @investor = '" & bondnumber & "', 
@linkedserver2 = 'binfodev', "PasswordCheck += "@sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + 
@linkedserver2 + ' WHERE bondno = ''@investor'' ' EXEC(@sql)"
```

It doesn't seem to be passing the variables properly in the query and i'm not sure where i'm going wrong

any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail please? Where are the variables not being passed properly to?

Comment: Remove the quotes from around the @linkedserver2 in the last PasswordCheck assignment. You don't need them because the VARCHAR is in a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the problem you are seeing specifically? More info would help.

What I can tell, is that you're code translates to a long line of SQL (substituting '69836' for `bondnumber`)

```
DECLARE @investor varchar(10), @thepassword varchar(20), @linkedserver2 varchar(25), @sql varchar(1000) SELECT @investor = '69836', @linkedserver2 = 'binfodev', @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @linkedserver2 + ' WHERE bondno = ''@investor'' ' EXEC(@sql)
```

I'll bet if you execute that in a query window it will fail. Try adding `;` at the end of each logical statement.

Have you considered just making this code a stored procedure and passing params to this? Code like this is pretty hazardous (SQL Injection), hard to read, and just a bit ugly in general.

**Sample Stored Procedure Code:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_MyStoredProcedure 
      @Param1 INT = NULL
AS

SELECT * FROM MyTable Where Col1 = @Param1
```

Comment: @Jamie Taylor - Really basic question, I'm afraid. I've included some sample stored procedure code, but I suggest you read up on them. Best of luck

Comment: You might also consider breaking the query out a bit if you don't use a stored proc. You can still benefit from using parameterized queries, even when doing it inline within your asp.net code.

Comment: It seems that I can't use stored procedures as we only have SQL SERVER 2000 - @Mike what do you by breaking the query out a bit?

Comment: @Jamie Taylor - SQL2000 has Stored Procedures, as did previous versions. Who told you that you couldn't?

Comment: When I try and connect to it using VS2010 I get an error saying this instance of SQL SERVER isn't supported

Comment: @Jamie - Well I personally tend to find it is much clearer to break things a part a little bit although its not technically necessary. I am just saying to build your parameter variables separately and then add them as parameterized:

Comment: @Jamie - Forget Visual Studio for the moment. Can you load up SQL Query Analyser (SQL2000 installed locally) or Management Studio (SQL2005+Installed locally). Here you can define your stored procedures and run ad-hoc queries.

Answer (score 0):

@Jamie - Well I personally tend to find it is much clearer to break things a part a little bit although its not technically necessary. I am just saying to build your parameter variables separately and then add them as parameterized (something like the following):

```
Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM @LinkedServer WHERE bondno = @BondNumber"
Dim c As New SqlConnection("Your Connection String Here")
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = c.CreateCommand()
With cmd
    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
    .CommandText = sql
    .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@LinkedServer", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = "binfodev"
    .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@BondNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = "69836"
End With
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
da.Fill(dt)
```